# Draw a Circle in 3D perpendicular to direction vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, circles, 3d

You People might have seen similar question everywhere, I have checked almost all of them but none of them satisfies my requirement. **:(**

**What I am Trying to achieve:** Trying to draw a Tube and Bend using circular Rings and them joining them to form a tube and bend.

**What Would be the best / Robust way to Draw a Circle in 3D ?** I have following parameters:

- Circle Center (global Coordinates)
- Radius
- Direction Vector **V** `( Point B (x,y,z) - Point A (x,y,z) )`

**Technique I already used**:

- Choose Arbitrary Vector **v1** e.g. [1,0,0]
- Cross Product to get a new othronormal vector **`v2 = CROSS ( V , v1 )`**
- Draw Circle using **v1 and v2**

[image]
here u = v1, and v= v2

> **Please Check the attached Code below:**

```
def circularpoints_v3(center, radius, normal, num_points=12):
# normal == direction Vector (V)

    v1 =v2 = np.array([0. , 0., 0.]).astype(np.float64) #z
    if True:
        if abs(normal[0]) > abs(normal[2]):
            b2 = np.array([-normal[1], normal[0], 0.0])
        else:
            b2 = np.array([0.0, -normal[2], normal[1]])
        b2 /= np.linalg.norm(b2)
        b1 = np.cross(b2, normal)
        v1 = b2
        v2 = b1
    circle = []
    angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num=num_points)
    for angle in angles:
        v1_Out = np.cos(angle) * v1 
        v2_Out = np.sin(angle) * v2
        point = center + (radius * (v1_Out + v2_Out ))
        circle.append(point)
```

**Issues:**
It is working **perfectly**, but I have almost every possible **combination of Direction Vector V**.

As a result, *I need an orthonormal basis for every **`V`**. BUT sometimes, the basis form does not equal the previous basis.* As a result, the **Circle starting and ending point Differ**. This is what I don't want because this would create a **TWIST** when I join all points.

[image]

Comment: Since your discretized circle is already polygon I think you can aling previous polygon with new polygon minimizing rotation of new polygon w.r.t previous polygon

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon Thanks for quick reply. Actually, in my opinion that wouldn't be robust solution to the problem and also How I would know That the basis is different from the previous one and according to that, change the order of the circle points for polygon.

What I was thinking, create a Circle in 2D, translate to Global coordinates, Rotate w.r.t to direction Vector. or Something like that https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ParametricEquationOfACircleIn3D/

Comment: If you're doing graphics and just want to draw a thin tube in a 3D scene, you might consider just drawing rectangles facing the camera and "faking" the surface normal direction (for lighting) using a fragment shader.

Comment: Your $v1$ is not orthogonal to $V$ in general, so the calculated set of $C(\theta)$ is in a plane _not_ orthogonal to $V$. Additionally, you did not mention nomalizing $v2$, so $C$ may be any ellipse, not necessarily a circle.

Comment: @CiaPan Please check my question now, I added my code in which I am normalizing each vector.

Answer (score 1):

When you move from one tube segment to the next, you can apply an appropriate minimal 3D rotation to the circle basis in order to keep it pointing in the right direction without any twisting. If the previous segment direction vector is $U$ and the new one is $V$, then you want a rotation by angle $\cos^{-1}(U\cdot V)$ around axis $U\times V$. This also works for determining the initial rotation.

With the scipy [Rotation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation) module, it should be something like this:

```
circle = np.array([[cos(t), sin(t), 0] for t in np.linspace(...)])
basis = np.identity(3)
for segment in tube_path:
    dir = direction(segment)
    prev_dir = basis[2]
    rot_angle = arccos(np.dot(prev_dir, dir))
    rot_axis = np.cross(prev_dir, dir)
    rot = Rotation.from_rotvec(rot_axis * (rot_angle / np.linalg.norm(rot_axis)))
    basis = rot.apply(basis)
    rotated_circle = circle @ basis
    positioned_circle = rotated_circle + midpoint(segment)
    results.append(positioned_circle)
```

Comment: Firstly, Thanks Karl, for you quick response :). I'm a little confused here by `incremental rotations` here. Could you please share some valuable resource regarding this?

secondly, Let's Say my circle is pointing along in X axis, then the v1 & v2 (orthonormal) could be Y or Z respectively. Then comes 2nd Circle, which points towards Y-axis, then then the v1 & v2 (orthonormal) could be X or Z respectively.  How to calculate the change in angle between them? is that the incremental angle you are talking about?

Comment: @Ansshakeel Does my edit make it clearer? I forgot you had used the names $v_1$ and $v_2$ for something else.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but not working, Tried with Quaternions and Rodrigues rotation. :(

Comment: @Ansshakeel Did you try something like the code I added?

Comment: Thank you for adding code, really helpful. Are you drawing circle in 2D? Actually, the code I'm using (pasted in my question) draws a circle in 3D using 3 orthonormal basis and I'm trying your code after it. is `midpoint` means the center of circle?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "are you drawing circle in 2D?" - this code generates all the circles along the tube in 3D coordinates. Is there a line you don't understand? I tried to name the variables to be self-explanatory. Each circle is centered around the midpoint of the corresponding path segment.

Comment: I completely understand your solution. BUT it is not working in case when both Normals of previous and current segment are same, then the `axis of rotation` would be `U×V
 = [0,0,0]` and rotation angle would also be `zero` because both Normals (U & V) are in the same directions i.e. `U =[1,0,0] , V =[1,0,0]` . Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: Good point. In that case, just don't apply any rotation.

Comment: But I want rotations in only such cases ;). `Basis Change` disturbs the points generation sequence. My final goal is not to make a perfect circle, I already achieved that now I'm only struggling to get same points sequence in every case like it must generate its `first point` on `X-axis` or any other defined axis.

Comment: Is there any way to make current BASIS `U , v1 , v2` equal to previous BASIS `V, u1, u2` and rotate the circle in the same rotation? But how to calculate angle and axis of rotation?

Comment: The same rotation as what? $U=V$ means the tube is not turning.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Given two tubes to synchronize

$$
p_i = p_0 + \lambda_i \vec v_i + r\left(\vec u_i\cos\theta_i+\vec w_i\sin\theta_i\right),\ \ \phi_i \in (-\pi,\pi],\ \ \ i = 1,2
$$

the trick is to determine a common phase origin. We can accomplish that by determining for which $\phi_0$ two lines from the family intersect , defining thus a phase common origin. We can do this by determining the minimum distance (it should be $0$) between

$$
\cases{
p_1 = p_0 + \lambda_1\vec v_1 + r(\vec u_1\cos 0+ \vec w_1\sin 0)\\
p_2 = p_0 + \lambda_2\vec v_2 + r(\vec v_2\cos\phi_0 +\vec w_2\sin\phi_0)
}
$$

Calling now $\delta(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\phi_0) = \|p_1-p_2\|^2$ we can derive the minimum conditions by solving for $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\phi_0)$

$$
\cases{
\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial\lambda_1}=0\\
\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial\lambda_2}=0\\
\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial\phi_0}=0
}
$$

or

$$
\cases{
(\lambda_1\vec v_1+r\vec u_1-\lambda_2\vec v_2-r(\vec u_2\cos\phi_0+\vec w_2\sin\phi_0))\cdot\vec v_1 = 0\\
(\lambda_1\vec v_1+r\vec u_1-\lambda_2\vec v_2-r(\vec u_2\cos\phi_0+\vec w_2\sin\phi_0))\cdot\vec v_2 = 0\\
(\lambda_1\vec v_1+r\vec u_1-\lambda_2\vec v_2-r(\vec u_2\cos\phi_0+\vec w_2\sin\phi_0))\cdot(-\vec u_2\sin\phi_0+\vec w_2\cos\phi_0) = 0\\
}
$$

or

$$
\left(\matrix{\|\vec v_1\|^2&-\vec v_1\cdot\vec v_2\\ \vec v_1\cdot\vec v_2& -\|\vec v_2\|^2}\right)\left(\matrix{\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2}\right)= r\left(\matrix{\vec v_1\cdot\vec u_2&\vec v_1\cdot\vec w_2\\ \vec u_2\cdot\vec v_2& \vec w_2\cdot\vec v_2}\right)\left(\matrix{\cos\phi_0\\ \sin\phi_0}\right)-r\left(\matrix{\vec u_1\cdot\vec v_1\\ \vec u_1\cdot\vec v_2}\right)
$$

once calculated $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ this result is substituted into the last equation remaining a last equation that should be solved for $\phi_0$.

Attached a plot showing the case

$$
\cases{
\vec v_1 = (1,1,1)\ \ \ \cases{\vec u_1 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right)\\ \vec w_1 = \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}},\sqrt{\frac 23}\right)}\\
\vec v_2 = (-2,-1,2)\ \ \ \cases{\vec u_2 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},0\right)\\ \vec w_2 = \left(-\frac{4}{3\sqrt{5}},-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{5}},-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}\right)}\\
p_0 = (0,0,0)\\
r = 2
}
$$

In red the lines of common phase and in black their intersection point.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for detailed answer. I'm just confused by some notations you used in your answer to actually code it. How you calculated λi, u and v ?

Comment: Included $\vec u_i, \vec w_i$. The $\lambda_i$ calculation is indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Geee... if indeed your goal is to draw a tube, why not simply use the right software tool, e.g., *Mathematica*:

```
Graphics3D[
 Tube[BSplineCurve[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}}], .3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, David, for your response. Actually, I'm using UnstructuredGrid in VTK and it does not support any CylinderSource or TubeFilters etc.